# USB Debugging / System Crash

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, usb, syslog

I have written a small program which generates 4 Audio Streams (sine waves) and sends them to 4 sound cards (each one connected to a USB port of the raspberry pi 3).

After a few seconds the pi completely freezes/crashes. I have to reboot the Raspberry Pi.

With just 3 Audio Streams (and 3 USB sound cards), everything works as expected.

The CPU load is actually ok (monitored with htop). The 4 CPUs are at about 30%.

However before crashing I can find the following entries in syslog:

```
Oct 11 18:48:13 pi kernel: [   51.983775] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=6 fsm=8 on transfer to device 4 ep 0x4
Oct 11 18:48:14 pi kernel: [   52.415833] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=2 fsm=9 on transfer to device 7 ep 0x1
Oct 11 18:48:14 pi kernel: [   52.991916] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=3 fsm=9 on transfer to device 4 ep 0x4
Oct 11 18:48:14 pi kernel: [   53.135930] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=2 fsm=9 on transfer to device 4 ep 0x4
Oct 11 18:48:15 pi kernel: [   53.268195] Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x4 frame 1995 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Oct 11 18:48:15 pi kernel: [   53.423974] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=3 fsm=9 on transfer to device 7 ep 0x1
Oct 11 18:48:15 pi kernel: [   53.567994] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=3 fsm=9 on transfer to device 4 ep 0x4
Oct 11 18:48:15 pi kernel: [   53.712005] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2619: Unexpected state received on hc=3 fsm=9 on transfer to device 7 ep 0x1
```

I suspect that there is some problem with the USB.

Are there any tools which could help me to monitor the USB ports? e.g. Buffers, Lost packets,...etc

What's the meaning of the syslog messages?

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: what O/S - is it headless? Hat is GPU memory allotment?

Comment: OS is Raspbian. Memory consumption remains at less than 100 Mbyte. So there is plenty of free memory remaining

Comment: It might be the power draw being asked from the USB audio devices. The Pi 3 has a **1.2A limit for maximum total USB peripheral current draw**

Comment: Thanks, in earlier projects I felt into this pitfall. But this time I've connected the Pi to a 4Amp Powersupply and I'm monitoring the USB voltage. The 4 sound cards are connected all the time, so I doubt its an issue with the Power supply.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was the power supply - it might be the USB power draw - the Pi 3 has a **USB limit** of 1.2A **TOTAL**. From what I understand, I think USB audio cards can draw from 0.5 to 0.9A - so that would be 2A minimum from my calcs. How are you monitoring the USB voltage - what numbers do you show?

Comment: I have one of these nifty USB measurement devices which measure voltage and current. Its between the Pi and the Powersupply. The total current is between 0.53A (idle - all 4 sound cards connected) and 0.61A (playing on all 4 sound cards).

Comment: Nice - I have to get one of those. I must have understood wrong - must be overall total current for all 4 USB Audio devices. Where'd you find one of those tools?

Comment: Are you running each program in a separate thread?

Comment: Just search on eBay for "USB Voltage Current Meter". They are really handy.

Comment: Yes, each stream is running async in its own stream